# Plot multiple histograms with purrr::map and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr

How do I plot the histograms for these four random variables . This works, but it seems unneccessarily long.

```
#libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
# Standard deviation question
std_devs %>% 
map(rnorm, n=1000, mean=75) %>% 
do.call('rbind', .) %>% 
t() %>% 
as.data.frame() %>% 
gather() %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x=value))+geom_histogram()+facet_wrap(~key)
```

Comment: what it `std_devs`?

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. The answer below figured out what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`purrr` is loaded by `tidyverse` so you can skip that line. `map_df` makes the rest much more condensed.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Standard deviation question
set.seed(10)
std_devs <- 1:4
std_devs %>% 
  map_df(~data_frame(key = ., value = rnorm(n=1000, mean=75, sd = .))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=value))+geom_histogram()+facet_wrap(~key)
```